# Django test loading css file

Tags: django, selenium, static

I have been trying to test whether a css file loads or not.

I tried using following code but it returns `404` code. The css file loads fine in browser.

```
client = Client()
response = client.get('/static/css/astyle.css')
self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code) # 200 != 404
```

How can I use selenium to test if a css file loads or not?

Comment: Are you sure `.get()` takes relative URL?

Comment: yeah according to the doc it does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was, I checked if the value of `div.row left margin` is `-15px` (bootstrap). It worked.

Answer (score 4):

The test server uses `DEBUG = False` regardless of what you specified in your settings.py file. Which implies that Django will not serve static files while running tests and that's why you are seeing 404 statuses.

I think instead of looking for a http status code, you could maybe test if the static file exist on the correct directory.

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.storage import staticfiles_storage #The file storage engine to use when collecting static files with the collectstatic management command.
from django.contrib.staticfiles import finders


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    self.assertTrue(staticfiles_storage.exists(finders.find('css/astyle.css')))
```

Of course, you'd need another test to see if your server config can serve static files, but that's outside the scope of django development.

Answer (score 1):

To make test requests to static files you can use [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#specialized-test-case-to-support-live-testing). 
Though the django test client will still return a 404. What worked for me was using urllib2 instead:

```
import urllib2
from hamcrest import assert_that, is_

url = self.live_server_url + os.path.join(settings.STATIC_URL, "foo.css")
request = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
assert_that(response.getcode(), is_(200))
```

Comment: Usually using urllib2, a test like this is outside the scope of Django tests exactly but this can be useful still in these types of situations (testing static) for example. Also, if you're going to use urllib2, you may as well use 'requests'.